# StackLayout is not viewable inside RelativeLayout

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to add a floating action button to my page, to do so I wrapped my stack layout with a relative layout and add the `FAB` in the relative layout.

```
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <RelativeLayout BackgroundColor="Transparent">
      <fab:FloatingActionButton
              x:Name="fabBtn"
              Source="plus.png"
              Size="Normal"
              Clicked="Handle_FabClicked"
              NormalColor="Green"
        RippleColor="Blue"
              RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1, Constant=-75}"
              RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=-75}" />
      <StackLayout
        Spacing="10"
        Padding="5"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
              RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}">
        <Label Text="Latest news/activities" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
        <ScrollView VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
          <ListView
            x:Name="lsvActivities"
            HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                  <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="3">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                      <Label Text="{Binding title}" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                      <Label Text="{Binding date}" VerticalOptions="End"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="End" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Blue">
                      <Label Text="image here"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                  </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
          </ListView>
        </ScrollView>
        <Label Text="Good Mording" FontSize="Large" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
      </StackLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
  </ContentPage.Content>
```

But it locks like the StackLayout is out of the boundary of the layout or something.

[image]

What is problem? and how I can display both the `FAB` and the StackLayout, where the floating action button should always be on top of the StackLayout elements

Comment: Can you remove the ScrollView? A ListView is already scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to have the StackLayout occupy the entire screen (with the button on top)? If so, this part isn't going to do that:

```
RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}">
```

That is placing the top left corner of the StackLayout at the bottom right of the screen.

Per the [Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/):

> Unlike AbsoluteLayout, RelativeLayout does not have the concept of the
>   moving anchor and does not have facilities for positioning elements
>   relative to the bottom or right edges of the layout.

In other words, AbsoluteLayout will try to adjust for you if you place something at the bottom right corner.  RelativeLayout won't.

You probably want the constraints noted above on the StackLayout to be WidthConstraint and HeightConstraint, and set the XConstraint and YConstraint to 0.

And as Sven-Michael says, drop the ScrollView.

**EDIT**

The XAML should look like:

```
RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}"
RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Constant=0}"
RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=Constant,Constant=0}"
```

Comment: Could you please show me how those two lines will be? I tried to make `Factor=0` but now the stackLayout's height is not expanded; I want the stacklayout's height to be as maximum as possible [imgur.com/a/W5GVW](http://imgur.com/a/W5GVW)

Comment: First, just try this: RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1}"
RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1}"

Comment: I want it to fully expand vertically, but there's a space beneath it. What I want is that the the FABs appear on top of the layout not under it.

Comment: There is no space beneath the StackLayout -- the Good Mording Label is at the very bottom of the screen.  So the StackLayout is taking up the entire screen now. This is now a different problem, where the ListView isn't taking up all available space within the StackLayout - try changing its VerticalOptions to FillAndExpand.